# Can you help me to understand this Magnitude/Phase to Real/Imaginary conversion?

Tags: complex-numbers

I've a module/function that takes an array of magnitudes/phases and get to me the real/img results.

These are the input values.
Magnitude values:

```
0
0.801315
0.380757
0.573996
0.859788
0.219944
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Phases:

```
-2.89749
-1.72549
1.40047
1.00661
-1.53623
0.988968
-2.13987
-1.7765
1.82693
-3.06451
-0.173057
-0.844002
-0.49597
2.39471
0.8022
-0.0507187
0.853398
-0.948891
-1.82233
2.01216
-1.09731
0.350813
2.30344
1.31015
-3.02846
0.694626
1.18897
-2.34984
0.452825
-2.2624
1.20948
2.16135
1.43959
-1.54774
-2.86604
-0.815814
-0.408722
-1.84342
-1.87218
-2.14198
-1.04036
0.247841
0.751769
-2.33297
-0.966724
3.01101
-2.09347
-3.04801
1.40526
2.39318
2.71091
0.599708
0.0581972
-0.0558961
0.332404
-1.16883
1.80047
1.98302
1.54007
-1.03096
0.866821
-0.809678
-2.10305
0.420994
-1.79797
0.651098
-1.35272
1.04458
2.00411
-1.5485
-0.51783
0.528184
-0.484465
-0.315338
0.405079
0.98705
0.00278034
1.96864
-1.71916
1.82885
0.681971
-0.932017
2.17285
1.64975
0.66222
-0.464139
-2.94754
-2.06566
2.63191
0.45225
-1.76365
-2.67678
1.69462
-0.290794
2.74869
2.08254
1.60852
1.48523
-1.18206
-1.89078
1.29194
-2.17477
3.07218
-1.92568
-1.87314
0.35273
-2.39586
1.66873
1.19357
-1.78628
0.374206
1.95368
0.43365
-2.03747
2.89154
0.316105
-2.02712
2.63747
2.3508
1.94697
-2.66221
-2.2275
0.403737
-1.67717
0.243431
2.65837
0.959821
2.86451
```

The output values are here. Real:

```
-0
-0.123466
0.0645398
0.306932
0.0297125
0.120871
-0
-0
-0
-0
0
0
0
-0
0
0
0
0
-0
-0
0
0
-0
0
-0
0
0
-0
0
-0
0
-0
0
0
-0
0
0
-0
-0
-0
0
0
0
-0
0
-0
-0
-0
0
-0
-0
0
0
0
0
0
-0
-0
0
0
0
0
-0
0
-0
0
0
0
-0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
-0
-0
-0
0
0
-0
-0
0
0
-0
-0
-0
0
-0
-0
-0
0
-0
-0
-0
0
0
-0
0
-0
-0
-0
-0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
0
-0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
-0
-0
-0
-0
-0
0
-0
0
-0
0
-0
0
```

Imaginary:

```
-0
-0.791746
0.375247
0.48504
-0.859274
0.183755
-0
-0
0
-0
-0
-0
-0
0
0
-0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
0
0
0
-0
0
0
-0
0
-0
0
0
0
-0
-0
-0
-0
-0
-0
-0
-0
0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
-0
0
0
0
0
0
-0
0
-0
0
0
0
-0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
0
-0
0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
-0
0
0
0
0
-0
0
0
-0
0
0
0
-0
-0
-0
0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
0
0
0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
0
0
-0
0
0
0
-0
0
0
-0
0
0
0
-0
-0
0
-0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Which are the formula that (from inputs) get to me outputs? i.e. how this module works? I don't get how it pass from input to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the magnitude be denoted by $r$ and the phase by $\phi$. Then any complex number z can be expressed as:

$z = r \exp(i\phi)$

Remembering that $\exp(it) = \cos(t) + i \sin(t)$ we can say:

$z = r (\cos(\phi) + i \sin(\phi)) = r\cos(\phi) + i r\sin(\phi) = \text{Re[z]} + i\text{Img[z]} $